# Why is layout different the first time the keyboard is shown vs. subsequent times?

Tags: android, layout, graphics, keyboard

[image] vs. 
[image]

I have an activity where a Button and an EditText have gravity set to bottom.

The first time the keyboard comes up, it moves the bottom elements up, just to the point where the cursor is above the keyboard. If I dismiss the keyboard and then click the EditText again, the bottom element are now moved up to the point where they are entirely above the keyboard.

I am wondering why this might be happening and what a workaround might be for having things laid out correctly right away?

**UPDATE:** As I look into this more, it turns out this seems to be a particular bug with Motorola devices (Droid Razr HD), as it is not exhibited on the Galaxy Nexus or HTC devices.